# Glide Framework running with Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, groovy, groovy-glide

I am trying to establish how widely used the Glide framework (http://glide-gae.appspot.com/) is on App Engine, I am looking for a RAD environment for developing on App Engine and came across these slides http://www.slideshare.net/kunal.dabir/rapid-app-dev-on-gae and I thought Glide was what I was looking for. 
I have downloaded and tried to follow the 2 minutes to fly steps  when I get to the step 4 and enter glide I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" : D:\Documents\dev\GAE\Glide\hello-glide\null\template does not exist
```

followed by an exception stack trace

I can get the example projects to run using

```
gradlew run -Papp=D:\glide\samples\simple_app
```

Comment: Might be better asking on the forum mentioned in those slides or raising a github issue?

Comment: Thanks for checking out glide, Am really sorry it's not working for you on windows. Can we discuss errors in details on the glide forum https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/glide-groovy .

Comment: Thanks, for the responses, I'd missed the link to the forum, have now registered and pursue from there

Answer (score 0):

Glide is currently work in progress but it's based on [Gaelyk Framework](http://gaelyk.appspot.com) which is already mature serving millions of requests a day. Glide just simplifies even more the already easy development (compared to pure Java) on Google App Engine.

Try to ask [Kunal](http://www.twitter.com/kdabir) directly for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I'd seen Gaelyk, the Gaelyk Community link seems to be down. Have you seen anything on using Gaelyk with Google endpoints for REST services? Will also contact Kunai

Comment: Ah, sorry for that community link. Gaelyk don't give you any enhancements for the endpoints, you can still write them in Java.